# Auto break line in CSS with return symbol

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, pre

I have to format a poem. the layout is responsive, but when the width decreases, and the poem container reduces his width, the poem goes out of him.
I'm using wordwrap for break the lines, but I wish to mantain a continuity for the two line parts.

```
pre {
      word-wrap: break-word;
      white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

It's possible to make something this (adding return symbol **↵**):

> ```
> Cold flower heads are raining over my heart.
> Oh pit of debris, fierce cave of the shipwrecked.
> ```

to

> ```
> Cold flower heads are↵
> raining over my heart.
> Oh pit of debris, fierce↵
> cave of the shipwrecked.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's a little complicated, but you have to use somthing like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="nowrap">Cold flower heads are&nbsp;</div><div class="nowrap">raining over my heart.</div><br />
<div class="nowrap">Oh pit of debris, fierce&nbsp;</div><div class="nowrap">cave of the shipwrecked.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nowrap {
    white-space:nowrap;
    float:left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jaAhk/2/ (Scale it!)

If you want to use it depends on how large the poem is, i guess.

Comment: This does not add any return symbol. It may address a question that should have been asked, but it does not address the question actually asked.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add content at ends of lines in CSS. The only way to add textual content is with the `content` property, which does not apply to the `:first-line` pseudo-element.

However, the goal of indicating continuation can be achieved in a different manner: by indenting the continuation lines. For this, you would need to make each logical line of the poem an element, e.g.

```
<div class=poem>
<div>Cold flower heads are raining over my heart.</div>
<div>Oh pit of debris, fierce cave of the shipwrecked.</div>
</div>
```

And you would indent continuation lines by setting left margin and nullifying it for the first line, by setting a negative value for `text-indent` (which indents the first line only):

```
.poem > div { margin-left: 1em; text-indent: -1em; }
```

Comment: This does neither solve the problem, nor address the question.

Comment: @weiglt, it specifically answers the question (“You cannot”) and additionally suggests a workaround, or an alternative approach, that achieves (in one way) the goal described in the text of the question. What else could an answer consist of?

Comment: I think you could use this approach and add a wrapping-marker, but only at the beginning of a line: On the line-divs use `background-image` (the picture of the marker) and set `background-position : 0 1em`. This will make the background image only visible, if the div contains more than one single line of text. I have not tried this, but it should work.